# Regular BSODs, particularly when playing games

Tags: windows, bsod

I'm getting regular BSODs when playing DOTA. The error message is usually related to memory corruption, although they seem to be getting weirder as time goes on, perhaps leading me to believe it is a motherboard issue. I have 2x16GB DDR4 RAM, and I've tested them each in isolation on memtest, both passed. When I tested them together, the test stopped functioning after an hour - no error, it just literally stopped doing anything.

Minidumps:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B_kMoYinePjeLWFPdHlCS3ZCU1k?usp=sharing

My build:
Gigabyte X99M-Gaming 5 Intel X99 (Socket 2011) DDR4 Micro ATX Motherboard

EVGA BQ 850W 80 Plus Bronze Semi Modular Power Supply

Intel i7-5820K 3.30GHz (Haswell-E) Socket LGA2011-V3 Processor - Retail (BX80648I75820K)

G.skill 32GB(16GBx2) G.SKILL Trident Z DDR4 PC24000 3000MHz C15 Kit - F4-3000C15D-32GTZ

Inno3D GeForce GTX 980 "iChill Herculez X4 Air Boss Ultra" 4096MB GDDR5 PCI-Express Graphics Card (C98U-1SDN-M5DNX)

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to analyze the problem with 'windbg'?

Comment: not sure if this will help  http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/faq/id-1655596/fix-kmode-exception-handled-error-windows.html     but also, there are a lot of malware forums like bleeingcomputer that have a section dedicated to analyzing those dumps, with people that will do it

Comment: Yes, that's how I got the Bugcheck Analysis at the bottom of the post. 

The error code seems different every time, which is very concerning. It is not always KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED. Sometimes it's MEMORY_CORRUPTION_ONE_BYTE or MEMORY_CORRUPTION_LARGE.

Answer (score 0):

[Analyzing the dump](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks) shows crashes related to memory issues.

you use 16GB RAM modules, and on the [support page](http://www.gigabyte.us/Motherboard/GA-X99M-Gaming-5-rev-10#support-dl) of your board I see that you need at least BIOS F4b to be able to use 16GB RAM modules.

So if you use an older BIOS update the BIOS.

Comment: Hmm... I can't find something that says this exactly. Where did you see this line?

Comment: I see it in the support link I posted. look at the Description for the BIOS downloads and look what is written for F4b

Comment: Already updated the bios, to no noticeable effect. Memtest still fails when both sticks are installed, and runs on each successfully.

Comment: [use CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) and look at the RAM timings and make sure the data from memory and SPD tab match

Comment: Have solved the problem, but not sure which element is incorrect. 

I used 4x8Gb DIMMs from a friend, and it works perfectly. I think it's actually the RAM speed, as mine is 3000, and Gigabyte only specifically say they cater to 2800 (despite the fact the splash screen says 2400+)

Comment: ok, so buy new RAM and post your finding as answer